# Drag & Drop events p-schedule PrimeFaces/PrimeNG Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeFaces/Primeng component in my Angular-CLI project. 
I want to create a p-schedule (It's FullCalendar) with Drag & Drop Events from outside into calendar but don't know how.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?  where is error in your code ?

Comment: Check my answer here:
[Angular 2 PrimeNG Scheduler onDrop event get date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791267/1180080)